# can not put file in redux array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, file, redux, react-redux

I am uploading file in redux array and it seems it is getting file as payload since it logs in console but when i push it in array it puts empty object instead of actual file, i haven't faced this problem so i do not know what to do so here is code:

```
const uploadImage = (e) => {
  const files = e.target.files;
  console.log(files)
  for(const file of Array.from(files)){
     console.log(file)
     dispatch({
       type: UPLOAD_IMAGE,
       payload: file
     });
  };
};
```

reducer:

```
case UPLOAD_IMAGE:
  console.log(action.payload)
  return {
    ...state,
    images: [...state.images, action.payload]
  }
```

here is payload

[image]

and here is redux devtools extension

[image]

Comment: v4.0.4 and also redux-thunk v2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new object for `Redux` first of all.
I don't know details, but putting `File`/`Blob` to `Redux` doesn't work the way it works with JS objects. If you have better solution, share with me, please )

```
    const file = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(`#file`);
    const blob = file.files[0];
    const blobForRedux = {};

    [
        'lastModified',
        'lastModifiedDate',
        'name',
        'path',
        'preview',
        'size',
        'type',
        'webkitRelativePath',
    ].map((key) => {
        blobForRedux[key] = blob[key];
    });
```